# EmptyPage error when the page already exist in django

Tags: python, django, templates, pagination

i have a problem with django.

I have created a pagination function and everything is fine, but when i try to enter to the last page of the pagination, i get the error `"EmptyPage this page does not contain results"`.

But that page really exists! there are items left but it doesn´t show me the five last items of the Query.

Here is my function:

```
def clasification(request):
    categoria = Clasificacion.objects.filter(existencia=True)
    paginator = Paginator(categoria, 5)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        items = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        items = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    contexto = {'meta_description':'',
                'meta_keywords':'',
                'items':items}
    return render(request, 'adminview/clasification.html', contexto)
```

Everything seems to be fine here...

Take a look of the HTML:

```
{% if items.has_next or items.has_previous %}
          <ul class="pagination">
            {% if items.has_previous %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ items.previous_page_number }}">Anterior</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link">Anterior</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% for page in items.paginator.page_range %}
            <li class="page-item {% if items.number == page %}active{% endif %}"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page }}">{{ page }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
            {% if items.has_next %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ items.next_page_number }}">Siguiente</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ items.next_page_number }}">Siguiente</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          </ul>
          {% endif %}
```

I dont know why i´m getting this error.

Hope you can help me.

Thank you!.

Comment: is the file `adminview/clasification.html` in `app/template` folder?

Comment: Yes, is ubicated on " 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')] ", , it means on `project/templates` folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template, you are trying to use `items.next_page_number` when `items.has_next` is false.

This will solve your problem:

```
{% if items.has_next %}
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ items.next_page_number }}">Siguiente</a></li>
{% else %}
  <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link">Siguiente</a></li>
{% endif %}
```